# Data dependency in module

Tags: javascript, ajax, module, xmlhttprequest

I am creating an Online Store App, made up of a few modules.
The first module is the Data module, which provides the data for the rest of the app as well as a few useful methods.
Here is the main gist of the module:

```
app.data = (function (pubsubService) {
//This is where the data is fetched
var items = app.UTILS.getAJAX('data.json', JSON.parse, false);
/* Items methods */
var getItems = function () {
    return items;
};
var getItemsLength = function () {
    return items.length;
};
function updateItemStock(item, amount) {
    item.stock -= Number(amount);
}
return {
    getItems: getItems,
    getItemsLength: getItemsLength;
};
})(app.pubsub);
```

The items var is called via Ajax, with the following helper function:

```
function getAJAX(url, callback, async) {
    async = async || true;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, async);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        callback(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

I've tried to make this call with Async on and off, and regardless of that, the result is an error, because later down the line there is another module which needs some information about the data, but the data loads only LATER, causing the error. The question is: How can I enforce the data to be loaded to items before moving on to initialisation of the next module?

*** EDIT ****
This is an example of another module, which is dependent on Data:

```
app.mainView = (function (data, pubsubService) {
var items = [];
var generateItems = function (firstItemIndex, stopIndex) {
    var dataLength = data.length;
    stopIndex = (stopIndex < dataLength) ? stopIndex : dataLength;
    items = data.slice(firstItemIndex, stopIndex);
    pubsubService.publish('itemsGenerated');
};
var getItems = function () {
    return items;
};

return {
    generateItems: generateItems,
    getItems: getItems
};
})(app.data.getItems(), app.pubsub);
```

Does this module really need to be defined inside the AJAX callback for this to work? I am not a fan of this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any operation that wants the data coming from Ajax needs to be written in Callback method. So whenever data is available your code will be invoked.

Call you method like following:

```
   getAJAX(url, function(data){
// write any code that want data from Ajax.
}, true);
```

Alternative:

```
function doSomeThing(data)
{
// do something
}

getAJAX(url, function(data){
    doSomeThing(data);
    }, true);

Or

getAJAX(url,doSomeThing, true);
```

Do not make call having Async false. it will cause you page UI response sluggish .

*** EDITED***

I have used your code to simplify it.

```
// Modified it in a method that can be put anywhere you want
app.methodName = function(data, pubsubService) {
    var items = [];
    var generateItems = function(firstItemIndex, stopIndex) {
        var dataLength = data.length;
        stopIndex = (stopIndex < dataLength) ? stopIndex : dataLength;
        items = data.slice(firstItemIndex, stopIndex);
        pubsubService.publish('itemsGenerated');
    };
    var getItems = function() {
        return items;
    };

    return {
        generateItems : generateItems,
        getItems : getItems
    };
};
```

And

```
// call that method in a callback like this. 
app.mainView  = app.methodName(app.data.getItems(), app.pubsub);
```

This is how you can write one line of code in callback to get your work done that will remove complexity also.

Comment: I thought of that, which brings me to my next question. Currently all my modules are immediately invoked (IIFEs), so to adopt what you suggest here I should actually make them called only after the call has been completed (as callbacks). To do this while keeping my code clean, I would want to define them outside of the AJAX scope and just reference it inside, which would require me to make my modules NOT IIFEs. What are your thoughts on that? Everywhere I looked at the module pattern, IIFE was suggested as the way to go. I don't want to over-complicate my code and want the simplest solution

Comment: I'm referring to the cross-modular dependency here (all other modules are dependent on data being resolved)

Comment: If i understood you explanation see my edited answer that can help.

Comment: Your answer does not really address my concern. Think about another module which consumes a method from Data. It is dependent on the data module being completely initialized, which depends on the data getting received. Should I really make all my modules live as the callback of this ajax call?

Comment: I edited my question and added the second module as an example, hopefully this will make my question more clear

Comment: Thank you for your help, this leads me to my second question (see my first comment) regarding the downsides of using the module pattern without an IIFE, but i think this requires a new topic. I will add it soon and comment you a link, for now i will accept your answer

Comment: IIFE is nothing but a way to immediately invoke a method, in other work it is short form of function. IIFE is recommended to use when you have less code to execute in a function. But in you case, where lines of code is more you should prefer normal function strategy.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought, but I still want to make sure I am not missing anything, since everywhere I read about the module pattern, it was all about IIFEs. I posted another question on this topic in the more broader sense (non-IIFE modules) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492081/modules-that-are-not-iifes). Feel free to contribute your thoughts there as well