# Modules that are not IIFEs

Tags: javascript, ajax, module, iife

See [Data dependency in module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31491466/3836205)

I have a few modules in my app which depend on data coming from the server. I implemented the modules as IIFEs, as the module pattern suggests, but in order to be able to reference them as the callback for the ajax request I am thinking of defining them as regular functions, and initialising them in the callback (see the answer in the other post for reference). Everywhere I looked, the module pattern consisted of IIFEs. What are the drawbacks(if any) of using them as regular functions which I instantiate in the AJAX callback? Is that a good practice?

Comment: Whether you call the function immediately (IIFE) or later doesn't really make a difference for the functionality. The function is only used to create "private" scope. It doesn't really matter *when* it's called.

Comment: …and if you don't need any private variables for the creation of your module, then you don't need an IIFE at all. Just put the value (object literal, function declaration, ajax promise etc) right there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at following example from previous post:

```
getAJAX(url, function(data){
         // write any code that want data from Ajax.
       }, true);
```

> This code contains IIFE function call. Here it is called an
>   `anonymous` function also. It is a way of invoking inline function and
>   has nothing to do with Modular approach.

See following Class representation in javascript:

```
var ClassName = function(data, pubsubService) {
var items = [];
// public function
this.generateItems = function(firstItemIndex, stopIndex) {
    var dataLength = data.length;
    stopIndex = (stopIndex < dataLength) ? stopIndex : dataLength;
    items = data.slice(firstItemIndex, stopIndex);
    pubsubService.publish('itemsGenerated');
};
// private function
var getItems = function() {
    return items;
};

return {
    generateItems : generateItems,
    getItems : getItems
};
};
```

> This is a class where `generateItems` is a public function and `getItems` is a private function.

Now in reference to you previous post, instead of creating regular function create a class as `module` which contains method of that module, create `object` and call methods like following:

```
Var obj = new ClassName(data,pubsubService);
obj.generateItems(firstItemIndex,stopIndex);
```

I think this can help you understand the concept.

Refer following link to explore more:

http://book.mixu.net/node/ch6.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/create-an-object-oriented-javascript-class-constructor.html#fbid=5m_t2A6hozg